# Amsmath package and overleaf

Tags: amsmath, babel, french

I have been using LaTeX (on the Overleaf platform) for a few years now, mainly in article and report class. Since I’m studying physics, I’ve more or less used the same packages for every new document without having an issue (or at least without something that could’nt be fixed easily).

Currently I am working on a new report (in order to have chapters, section etc. well organised) and it won’t compile unless I get rid of the amsmath package. I really don’t understand where it comes from since it’s one of the main packages I use. I’ve tried to put the package on the top of the list (like it was suggested in another post) but nothing changes.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{french}[babel]
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{blindtext}


\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[a4paper,tmargin=2.5cm,bmargin=2.5cm,             
                     rmargin=3cm,lmargin=3cm]{geometry}


\title{Mécanique des structures\\Théorie des poutres}
\author{D'après le cours de  Mr.Rotinat par 72Ch221 }
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\part{Bases de la théorie des poutres}
\chapter{Généralités sur la théorie des poutres}
\section{Origine de la théorie des poutres}
La résolution rigoureuse de problèmes de mécanique des solides élastiques peut très rapidement s'avérer difficile et longue lorsqu'il s'agit d'étudier un élément d'un système mécanique ayant une géométrie et des sollicitations complexes. Afin de rendre les calculs plus rapides, voire possibles dans certains cas, et ainsi permettre et simplifier leur dimensionnement, il est nécessairee d'introduire les hypothèses simplificatrices. \\
La mécanique des structures concerne ainsi le cas où des hypothèses sur le chargement sont introduites, càd pour la mécanique des solides de dimensions finies où une des dimensions au moins est faible devant les autres et introduit un certain nimbre d'hypothèses simplificatrices. Ainsi l'observation des structures permet notamment de classer leurs éléments en trois catégories en fonction de leur géométrie : soit les solides ayant une symétrie de révolution appelés solides axisymétriques, soit une dimension grande devant les deux autres et cela définit les poutres. On se limitera par la suite au seul cas des poutres. La résistance des matériaux correspond quant à elle à la mécanique des structures restreint à l'élasticité linéaire. \\\\
L'objectif de la mécanique des structures est de vérifier la bonne tenue en service des éléments des structures en prenant en compte des critères tels que la sécurité ou encore viabilité économique en ramenant l'étude du comportement global d'une structure (relation entre sollicitations, forces ou moments, et déplacements) à celle du comportement local des matériaux la composant (relation entre contraintes et déformations) pour réaliser un dimensionnement convenable.

\end{document}
```

I’ve added the beginning of my code and as simple as it appears it won’t compile anyway.
Hope you’ll be able to help me !

Comment: it should be `\usepackage[french]{babel}`. (your braces are wrong). And don't use `\\\\ `, use empty lines to create a paragraph and load the parskip packag if you want larger paragraph spaces.

Comment: Off-topic: Instead of `tmargin=2.5cm, bmargin=2.5cm,  rmargin=3cm, lmargin=3cm`, use the simpler `vmargin=2.5cm,hmargin=3cm`. (`v` and `h` are short for vertical and horizontal, respectively.)

Comment: @ulrikefisher Ohhh  I didn’t see that one, must have been a typo !! Thank you so much, it’s working neatly now !  thanks for the advice about the paragraph !

Comment: @Mico Thanks for the advice about the margins ! Will be doing that from now

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions (some already provided by @UlrikeFischer):

- The main problem you report has nothing to do with the `amsmath` package. Instead, it's caused by a syntax error in the line immediately before `\usepackage{amsmath}`. To fix the syntax error, just replace

  ```
  \usepackage{french}[babel]
  ```

  with

  ```
  \usepackage[french]{babel}
  ```
- I recommend you also execute `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` in the preamble. (LaTeX must have been nagging you about this for a long time...)
- Replace all instances of `\\` and `\\\\` [!] in the input file with blank lines. (Blank lines trigger paragraph breaks automatically.) And, add the instruction `\setlength{\parskip}{1\baselineskip}` in the preamble, right after setting the `\parindent` length to zero. Better still, don't actually execute the  instructions that modify the `\parskip` and `\parindent` length parameter; instead, just run

  ```
  \usepackage[skip=1\baselineskip,indent=0pt]{parskip}
  ```

  By loading the `parskip` package in this way, you'll avoid some unfortunate spacing issues that could arise after sectioning commands.
- Don't load the `amsfonts` package directly. Instead, load the `amssymb` package (which loads `amsfonts` automatically).

---

Here's how an adjusted version of your code could look like:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}   % <-- new
\usepackage[french]{babel} % <-- corrected
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb} % <-- 'amssymb' loads 'amsfonts' automatically

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{blindtext}

%%\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
%%\setlength{\parskip}{1\baselineskip} % <-- new
\usepackage[skip=1\baselineskip,indent=0pt]{parskip} % <-- new

\usepackage{longtable}
%\usepackage[a4paper,tmargin=2.5cm,bmargin=2.5cm,             
%                     rmargin=3cm,lmargin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[a4paper,vmargin=2.5cm,hmargin=3cm]{geometry} % <-- simplified


\title{Mécanique des structures\\Théorie des poutres}
\author{D'après le cours de  Mr.Rotinat par 72Ch221 }
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\part{Bases de la théorie des poutres}
\chapter{Généralités sur la théorie des poutres}
\section{Origine de la théorie des poutres}

La résolution rigoureuse de problèmes de mécanique des solides élastiques peut très rapidement s'avérer difficile et longue lorsqu'il s'agit d'étudier un élément d'un système mécanique ayant une géométrie et des sollicitations complexes. Afin de rendre les calculs plus rapides, voire possibles dans certains cas, et ainsi permettre et simplifier leur dimensionnement, il est nécessairee d'introduire les hypothèses simplificatrices. 

La mécanique des structures concerne ainsi le cas où des hypothèses sur le chargement sont introduites, càd pour la mécanique des solides de dimensions finies où une des dimensions au moins est faible devant les autres et introduit un certain nimbre d'hypothèses simplificatrices. Ainsi l'observation des structures permet notamment de classer leurs éléments en trois catégories en fonction de leur géométrie : soit les solides ayant une symétrie de révolution appelés solides axisymétriques, soit une dimension grande devant les deux autres et cela définit les poutres. On se limitera par la suite au seul cas des poutres. La résistance des matériaux correspond quant à elle à la mécanique des structures restreint à l'élasticité linéaire. 

L'objectif de la mécanique des structures est de vérifier la bonne tenue en service des éléments des structures en prenant en compte des critères tels que la sécurité ou encore viabilité économique en ramenant l'étude du comportement global d'une structure (relation entre sollicitations, forces ou moments, et déplacements) à celle du comportement local des matériaux la composant (relation entre contraintes et déformations) pour réaliser un dimensionnement convenable.

\end{document}
```